# FormsAuthentication timeout issue

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Session["User"] = "Authenticated";
                Session["Username"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");
            }

        }

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           int recordExistCount = fc.Authenticate(txtUsername.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());
           if (recordExistCount == 1)
           {
               Session["User"] = "Authenticated";
               Session["Username"] = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
               fc.IsOnlineRecord(Session["Username"].ToString(),true);
               var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(2,Session["username"].ToString(),DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes), true,"",FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
               var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
               var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
               {
                   HttpOnly = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL,
                   Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
                   Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain
               };
               Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
               Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");  
           }

 <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="LoginPage.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="60"
           name=".ASPXAUTH"
           path="/"
           requireSSL="false"
           slidingExpiration="true"
           defaultUrl="HomePage.aspx"
           cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
           enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
      </authentication>
```

My page times out when its left idle for more than 10 mins. I wonder what is going wrong?

Comment: Are you running under SSL during development?

Comment: requireSSL property of forms tag is set to false

Comment: Take a look at this, its not the same but similar, almost reverse http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WeirdTimeoutsWithCustomASPNETFormsAuthentication.aspx

Comment: What web server are you using? Is this happening on a development server (VS Dev. Server or IIS Express?) or are you using IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be your session that is timing out, not the Form. Have you set the session timeout in the Web.Config? This can be done in the sessionState element (inside the system.web element)

Check this link for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: I have included the sessionstate tag and specified the timeout to 60 mins